# why input field necessary to run Raphael?

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, graphael

why input field necessary to run Raphael ?
I have just build Raphael animation with another inspiring code. Customised code working well but unfortunately the code doesn't work without input field.

```
<input type="text" value="70" id="radius12">
<input type="text" value="#fff" id="color">
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/V54hR/
does any body have any clue why it is necessary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have small typo in your code, Input field are not necessary for Raphael. When you give `<input type="text" value="#fff" id="color">` this  Raphael assumes color variable as your input field

```
colour = "#000",
```

change this code to

```
color = "#000",
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V54hR/1/)